# Adding a label on a margin (instead of line number) in pseudo code

Tags: numbering, algorithms

I would like to mark (e.g. with a *)a line in a pseudo code typesetted with the `algorithmic` package. I would like the label to appear on the left margin, instead of the line number. Is that possible?. I would like to have something like this:

```
  a = 5
  b = 7
* if a < b then
    ...
  end if
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `algpseudocode` from the [`algorithmicx` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx), you can momentarily redefine the line number printing macro `\alglinenumber`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State $a=5$
  \State $b=7$
    \algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\footnotesize$\star$\phantom{:}}
  \If{$a<b$}
    \algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\footnotesize #1:}
    \State \ldots
  \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

The renewal is done *before* the command statement, since `algorithmic` is set as a list, with each `\State` being an item in the list, and having a subsequent number printed *before* the actual item content.