# Algorithms: change the style of individual line numbers

Tags: algorithm2e, algorithmicx

I would like to change the style of individual lines in an algorithm. For example, I'd like surround key line numbers with a box, color them, or otherwise distinguish them.

It is possible to change the style of all the line numbers with algorithm2e, as detailed here (and in the manual): [Algorithm2e modify line numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100145/algorithm2e-modify-line-numbers?rq=1)

Is there a way to modify the style of an arbitrary subset of the lines?

Comment: From what I remember from the answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239646/algorithmicx-print-first-line-number-when-numbering-every-n-th), it's not really easy… But you could try to build on that!

Answer (score 1):

Building on this answer [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65572/adding-a-label-on-a-margin-instead-of-line-number-in-pseudo-code), this can be accomplished by updating the `\alglinenumber` command, as follows. This isn't yet an optimal solution, as demonstrated by the last line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\StateRed}[1]{\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\footnotesize\textcolor{red}{##1}:}\State #1}
\newcommand{\StateBlack}[1]{\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\footnotesize##1:}\State #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \StateRed $x = 1$
  \StateBlack $y = 2$
  \StateRed $ z = 3$
  \State you probably didn't want this to be red!
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This also doesn't work perfectly when adding annotations of non-zero width to the line numbers, as the spacing is affected when going from line 9 to 10 (and presumably 99 to 100, though I have not checked).